# How can I replace a string in parentheses using a regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string:

```
HLN (Formerly Headline News)
```

I want to remove everything inside the parens and the parens themselves, leaving only:

```
HLN
```

I've tried to do this with a regex, but my difficulty is with this pattern:

```
"(.+?)"
```

When I use it, it always gives me a `PatternSyntaxException`.  How can I fix my regex?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Because parentheses are special characters in regexps you need to escape them to match them explicitly.

For example:

```
"\\(.+?\\)"
```

Comment: He might want .+? if there may be several parenthetized pieces.

Comment: yes, she. I put "?" just in case multiple parenthized case.
@jjnguy: thanks for the explaination. It works!

Answer (score 17):

```
String foo = "(x)()foo(x)()";
String cleanFoo = foo.replaceAll("\\([^\\(]*\\)", "");
// cleanFoo value will be "foo"
```

The above removes empty and non-empty parenthesis from either side of the string.

plain regex:

```
\([^\(]*\)
```

You can test here: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

My code is based on previous answers

Answer (score 11):

You could use the following regular expression to find parentheticals:

```
\([^)]*\)
```

the `\(` matches on a left parenthesis, the `[^)]*` matches any number of characters other than the right parenthesis, and the `\)` matches on a right parenthesis.

If you're including this in a java string, you must escape the `\` characters like the following:

```
String regex = "\\([^)]*\\)";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String foo = "bar (baz)";
String boz = foo.replaceAll("\\(.+\\)", ""); // or replaceFirst
```

`boz` is now `"bar "`