# How To Replace A Number In Brackets With Regex

Tags: java, regex, string, brackets

Well I have this code:

```
String replacedItemName = ItemDefinitions.getItemDefinitions(usedWith).getName().replaceAll("\\(.\\)", "(6)");
```

Is `\\(.\\)` the correct regex to replace anyting in the brackets of the item name? (Java)

Comment: Instead of changing your question to something entirely different, and thus having the answers make no sense at all, you should accept the correct answer and start a new question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace string in parentheses using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138552/replace-string-in-parentheses-using-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `replaceAll("(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))", "6");`. See [here](http://rubular.com/r/Txs3qmvHeP)

Answer (score -1):

Almost, you forgot a plus (one-or-more) after your dot. Without the plus, the dot only matches one character.

```
\(.+\)
```

However, I am unsure what strings you are targeting. I've made a Rubular with some examples:

http://rubular.com/r/0WijBsdtV0

Do these match your intended behavior?

Comment: @Uhehesh: No need to escape the `)` inside `[]`s.

Comment: Don't use `\(.+\)` - it is greedy and can match more then you want! >> http://rubular.com/r/ANfAVC1nJd

Comment: @Ωmega I know, I even included this limitation in one of my examples in the Rubular snippet. I am not sure what his scenario is, so I do not know if his input string will contain a single block of parentheses or multiple blocks. By showing him a Rubular with some examples I hope he can figure out his own solution.