# using parenthesis replaceAll method Java

Tags: java, string, match, replaceall

I would like to change a word in a sentence, but the word has parenthesis. I keep it in the String variable. Inside of the variable **st** I have

`manages(P0,MT0)`

Inside of other String variable `DES` I have the following sentence:

`query(MT0, P0) :- not(manages(P0,MT0)), ins_manages(P0,MT0), not(physician(P0)), not(ins_physician(P0))`

SO I have another string variable `querypart` which stores the new word:

`managesa`

What I tried in the code was:

```
EDC = EDC.replaceAll(st,querypart);
```

but it did not work.

I thought the problem might be paranthesis, so I changed the string like st variable like:

`manages\\(P0,MT0\\)`

then I tried

```
EDC = EDC.replaceAll(st,querypart);
```

but I had the some result. The problem is when I use the replaceAll like that:

```
EDC = EDC.replaceAll("manages\\(P0,MT0\\)",querypart);
```

The sentence changes

`query(MT0, P0) :- not(managesa), ins_manages(P0,MT0), not(physician(P0)), not(ins_physician(P0))`

I guess it is because of parenthesis but I could not find any solution for that? What is the solution?

Comment: Why you won't to use regular expressions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138552/replace-string-in-parentheses-using-regex)

Comment: What do you want the result to be? It looks like the only part of your "EDC" string that changed is the part that you wanted to change: `manages(P0,MT0)` was replaced with `managesa`. Is that not the result you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you wanted to use [`String#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) (not `replaceAll`), this

```
String EDC = "query(MT0, P0) :- not(manages(P0,MT0)), "
    + "ins_manages(P0,MT0), not(physician(P0)), not(ins_physician(P0))";
String queryPart = "managesa";
EDC = EDC.replace("manages(P0,MT0)", queryPart);
System.out.println(EDC);
```

Output is

```
query(MT0, P0) :- not(managesa), ins_managesa, not(physician(P0)), not(ins_physician(P0))
```

Comment: not exactly what I use is variables and I don't fill by myself so EDC replace should be EDC = EDC.replace(st, queryPart); but in this case I can't get any change.

Comment: Read my code again please. I change the first and the second `manages(P0,MT0)`. What do you want the output to be?