# Groovy: Replace combination of , and )

Tags: regex, groovy

How do I replace comma and right parantheses at the same time, **,')**  with **)**, in groovy?
I tried replaceAll with double escape

```
value = "('cat','rat',',')";
//Replace  ,')  with )
value = value.replaceAll('\\,')',')');
```

Tried these with no luck
 [How can I replace a string in parentheses using a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138552/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-parentheses-using-a-regex)

[How to escape comma and double quote at same time for CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451842/how-to-escape-comma-and-double-quote-at-same-time-for-csv-file)

Comment: Try [`value.replaceAll("(,|^)','", "")`](http://ideone.com/9vKmGs) if you want to remove all values equal to `','` both from the start of the string and inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit cofusing, but to replace `,')` you don't need escapes at all. Simply use

```
def value = "('cat','rat',',')";
println value.replace(",')", ")"); // ('cat','rat',')
```

---

However, I think you rather want this result `('cat','rat')`. Right?

If so, you can use the following code, using [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

def value = "('cat','rat',',')";
def pattern = Pattern.compile(",'\\)");
def matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
while (matcher.find()) {
    value = matcher.replaceAll(")");
    matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
}
println value; // ('cat','rat')
```

Explanation:

You are creating the second replaceable text with your regex, it's not there when you try to replace it, but get's created as a result of the first replacement. So we create a new matcher in the loop and let it find the string again...